# Create Grails documentation - gdoc

Tags: grails

When I take a look at the great looking Grails Reference Documentation (http://grails.org/doc/latest/) and compare it with my lousy gdoc documentation, I wonder what makes the difference?

- is it just a different style sheet?
- or do they use another tool?

How do I get these great looks for my own project without having too much to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way to get the new look is to upgrade to 2.0M1 which uses the new look and feel. Peter Ledbrook created the current 1.3.7 docs with the new approach but I'm not sure how easy it'd be to do for a regular Grails application. And there are obviously many reasons to upgrade to 2.0.

You might want to wait a day or so - we're planning on releasing M2 this week. But upgrading from M1 to M2 will be trivial. The real work will be upgrading from 1.3 to 2.0, which isn't that bad.

Comment: Thanx. That's what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 2):

They use the same exact documentation building tool. It's clearly customized CSS but nothing else. You can read more about it in the [reference documentation itself](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/3.%20Configuration.html#3.6%20Project%20Documentation).

> Since Grails 1.2, the documentation engine that powers the creation of this documentation is available to your Grails projects.

From the documentation itself.

Comment: The link in the answer is obsolete